# Sinon Mocha Node Error Handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, sinon

server.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    lib.doSomething(x, y, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw(err);

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end(data);
    });
});
```

serverTest.js

```
var request = require('request');
var server = require('server');

    it('throws error when doSomething returns err', function(done){

      var expected = 'testError';

      doSomething = sinon.stub(lib, 'doSomething', function(x, y, callback){
        callback(new Error(expected));
      });

      try{
        request(url, function(err, response, body){
          done();
        });
      } catch(e){
        expect(e).to.equal(expected);
      };

    });
```

I approached this unit test many ways but whenever I run the tests, I keep getting a      `Uncaught Error: testError` and the test fails.  I looked around online and found no luck.  What would be the best approach to have this unit test passing with expected errors?

Comment: Where is your reference to `lib` coming from in serverTest.js?

Comment: sorry there should be a var lib = require('lib')

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a process that is talking to itself through a socket. `server.js` establishes a service that listens for requests on a socket and responds, and then your test code connects to that socket and makes requests. Now, the thing is that the call stack for the server side and the call stack for the client side are completely different stacks. **If the server throws an exception, your client cannot catch it.** In other words, your `request` call won't throw an exception because `lib.doSomething`'s callback does. You could trivially check that the callback threw an exception but then that's not testing much.

Comment: I did think about testing the callback but you're right, it wouldn't be testing anything at all.  How would I go about better designing the server and/or test?